# how to return a number with 2 decimal places all the time from a function

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, type-conversion

I have a random number generator function that returns a random number. It looks like the problem is that sometimes it returns only one decimal place the, tenths place(i think it's called). I always want it to output a **number** with **2 decimal places** (some times i would get 10.5 when i want 10.50).

in my code i put a plus sign to convert it into a number.I believe this is what is causing the hundredth's place to be deleted. what is the best way to solve this problem?

```
function randomGen() {
    return +(Math.random() * 11).toFixed(2)
}
// console.log(randomGen())
// some times i would get 10.5 when i want 10.50
var num1 = randomGen(); // i want 10.50, for example not 10.5
var num2 = randomGen();
console.log(num1, " ", num2)

console.log(+(num1 + num2).toFixed(2))
```

Thank you

Comment: that unary operator in the randomGen() function is pointless and will try to round that number, hence you should just remove it and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the + signs and you should be fine:

```
function randomGen(){
        return (Math.random()*11).toFixed(2)
    }
     // console.log(randomGen())
     // some times i would get 10.5 when i want 10.50
    var num1 = randomGen(); // i want 10.50, for example not 10.5
    var num2 = randomGen();
    console.log(num1, " ", num2)

    console.log((num1 + num2).toFixed(2))
```

If you want to convert a string to a number in JavaScript, use the 'parseFloat' function. Be aware that if you convert a string to a number, it will always cut off the decimal zeroes (for example 10.50 becomes 10.5).

Use numbers to make calculations and after you have the final result, convert it to string with the 'toFixed' method, so you can display it with two decimal places.

Comment: Doesn't that make it into a string? I would like it to return a number with 2 decimal place all the time.

Comment: Yes it does, I'll make an edit to my answer to clarify

Comment: `var snum1 = randomGen();
         var snum2 = randomGen();
         console.log(snum1, " ", snum2)
         var nnum1 = + snum1;
         var nnum2 = + snum2;
         console.log(nnum1 + nnum2)`

Comment: snum1 and snum2 are the strings to display and nnum1 and nnum2 is to perform operation on numbers. is that a good way to do it?

Comment: Just use the Int-values, there should be no problems. You don't have to convert everything to string. Convert only if the given type doesn't have the possible ways to handle something, like strings have methods like substr or when you really need it.

Answer (score 2):

> in my code i put a plus sign to convert it into a number.I believe this is what is causing the hundredth's place to be deleted. what is the best way to solve this problem?

Yes - **don't** convert it to a number!
Numerically, there is no such thing as `10.50`. There is only `10.5`
Only a string is capable of holding a value like `10.50`, and you **get** a string from `toFixed()`, but then convert it back to a number.

So I couldn't have said it better than [itd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30703061/2302862):

> Loose the + signs

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
randomGen(){
   result=(Math.random()*11)
   return parseFloat(result,10).toFixed(2)
    }
```